# A partial converse of Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $V\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open and $f\colon V\to \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function, and assume

$$
\int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz =0
$$

for any closed contour $\gamma \in V.$ We need to show that $f$ has an antiderivative $F$ defined on $V$.

I know how to prove it when $V$ is a convex open set and $\gamma \in V$ is a boundary of any triangle in $V.$ I do not know how to connect these ideas. Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: There is a proof in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem .

Comment: Since the contour integral is zero over any closed curve, then it is eqsy to show that the integral does not depend on the curve, but only on the extrema. So you can define the antiderivative to be $F(z):=\int_a^z f(w)dw$ where $a\in V·$ is a prefixed point and the integral is taken over ANY path $\gamma$ conecting $a$ and $z$ INSIDE $V$.

Comment: 1. I know why the integral of a holomorphic function would depend only on the extrema. Why does the same work for continuous functions?
2. Why would such a $\gamma$ connecting $a$ and $z$ be contained in $V$, say, if they are in two different connected components? In particular, why would the integral be defined?

Comment: 1. Because the proof doesn't use holomorphicity in the holomorphic case, either. It holds for any function that all closed integrals vanish if and only if all integrals only depend on the extrema. 2. You can consider each connected component of $V$ separately.

Comment: Thank you so much.